# Shared Elements Transitions only working in 2/3 cases

Tags: android, animation, element, transition, shared

I was playing around with the Shared Element Transition and developed a testapp with 4 Fragments.

[image]

In the picture you can see, the first Fragment contains a "start now" message, when it's clicked I want to replace the container with the Fragment in the middle. As an eye candy I want an Animation by using Shared Element Transitions.

**Problem**
My Problem is, if I leave the first Fragment empty (without starting message) and I for example set the OnClickListener to the Icon itself, everything is working alright with a nice animation. But if the first Fragment has that message in it **only the first** Icon (the second Fragment, picture in mid) doesn't have an animation anymore. It's just replacing the first fragment. The curios thing is, if I change my OnClickListener and let it start the second page (right picture) the animation is working fine again. So only the first/left Icon does not provide an animation though all Methods and XML are mostly 1:1 the same.

As I couldn't develope a better solution, each "toolbar" is designed in the Fragment itself.

**Main Activity**

```
 public class FirstStartupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_firststartup);
    doFragmentTransaction(new MainFragment(), "TAG", false, null);
}

public void doFragmentTransaction(Fragment fragment, String tag, boolean addToBackStack, List<View> sharedElements){
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.ActivityFirstStartup_fragmentContainer, fragment, tag);
    if(addToBackStack){
        transaction.addToBackStack(tag);
    }
    if( sharedElements != null && !sharedElements.isEmpty()){
        for(int i = 0; i < sharedElements.size(); i++){
            View view = sharedElements.get(i);
            transaction.addSharedElement(view, view.getTransitionName());
        }
    }
    transaction.commit();
}}
```

**First Fragment with Message**

```
 public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_firststartup_home, container, false);

    View view = v.findViewById(R.id.relLayoutPageOne);
    final List<View> listview = new ArrayList<>();
    listview.add(view);
    View view2 = v.findViewById(R.id.relLayoutPageTwo);
    final List<View> listview2 = new ArrayList<>();
    listview2.add(view2);

    Button button = v.findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((FirstStartupActivity)getActivity()).doFragmentTransaction(new UsernameFragment(), "test", true, listview);
            //((FirstStartupActivity)getActivity()).doFragmentTransaction(new CameraFragment(), "TEST2", true, listview2);
        }
    });

    RelativeLayout rel2 = v.findViewById(R.id.relLayoutPageTwo);
    rel2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((FirstStartupActivity)getActivity()).doFragmentTransaction(new CameraFragment(), "TEST2", true, listview2);
        }
    });

    return v;
}}
```

**Second Fragment No Animation**

```
 public class UsernameFragment extends Fragment {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_firststartup_pgone, container, false);
    postponeEnterTransition();
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        setSharedElementEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(getContext()).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move));
    }
}}
```

**Third Fragment Working**

```
 public class CameraFragment extends Fragment {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_firststartup_pgtwo, container, false);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        setSharedElementEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(getContext()).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move));
    }
}}
```

**Second Fragment (Picture in middle) No Animation when replacing)**

```
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@drawable/draw_login_edittext">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relLayoutPageTwo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/draw_login_edittext_rounded"
    android:transitionName="ProfileCam"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:transitionName="ProfileCam"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/testtwo" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relLayoutPageThree"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/draw_login_edittext_rounded"
    android:transitionName="ProfileGender"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.95"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/testthree" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:transitionName="ProfilePic"
    android:layout_width="273dp"
    android:layout_height="210dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/draw_login_edittext_rounded"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout2">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/test" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**First Fragment (Picture left)**

```
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#a8655c">
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:transitionName="ProfilePic"
    android:id="@+id/relLayoutPageOne"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/draw_login_edittext_rounded"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.049"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/test" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relLayoutPageTwo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/draw_login_edittext_rounded"
    android:transitionName="ProfileCam"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/testtwo" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relLayoutPageThree"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/draw_login_edittext_rounded"
    android:transitionName="ProfileGender"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.95"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/testthree" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:forceHasOverlappingRendering="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/draw_login_edittext_rounded"
    android:padding="25dp"
    android:transitionName="ProfilePic"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout2">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Bevor du loslegen könnst benötigen wir noch kurz ein paar Informationen über dich! :)"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#BFFFFFFF" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonStart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/text"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/draw_rounded_edittext_dark"
        android:text="Start now"
        android:textColor="#BFFFFFFF" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Third Fragment (right Picture) Animation when replacing**

```
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@drawable/draw_login_edittext">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relLayoutPageOne"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/draw_login_edittext_rounded"
    android:transitionName="ProfilePic"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.049"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/test" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relLayoutPageThree"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/draw_login_edittext_rounded"
    android:transitionName="ProfileGender"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.95"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/testthree" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="273dp"
    android:layout_height="210dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="#c8c8c8"
    android:transitionName="ProfileCam"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout2">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/testtwo" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Visual Description**

First Icon doesn't work but the second one works like charm
For some Reason the first GIF is way too fast, its popping up normally the only Problem is the missing Animation

[image]

[image]

Comment: In your xml code you slow that you set the transition names to each image, but how do you set them in your destination fragment that is in the center?

Comment: The complete screen containing the "Toolbar" (You can say its just fake, the actual Toolbar is only the coloured empty constraint in Top of every XML File) is changed. So on the First Screen all Transitionnames are in the Relative Layouts on Top and then the whole container gets replaced by for example Fragment 2, and the RelativeLayout in the center contains the second Transition name. If you watch the XML "First Fragment" you can find the Transition name in the First Relative Layout and in the XML "Second Fragment" you can find it in the last relative Layout

Comment: did you try `startPosponedEnterTransition()` from `window?.decor?.viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener()`?

Comment: No didn't try that yet, where do I have to put it. In the second Fragment?

Comment: Make sure to tag users with `@`  so that they get a notification about your message. My guess is that it may be a transition name mix up (but maybe not) or it may be the fact that you postpone the transition in `onCreate` and start it in `onCreateView`. Maybe your views don't have time to be drawn before the animation. What @HawkPriest suggests is centered around that I believe, which is postpone until the views are drawn and then launch the transition.

Comment: @LieForBananas Oh okay I will  mark HawkPriest then. I just saw I have postpone in my Fragment, but that was only a try it didn't change anything. The curios thing is, if i leave the first Fragment empty (without that button etc) and I put the onClickListener to the RelativeLayout Icon itself all three SharedElementTransitions work fine. The problem does only occur when the first Fragment has the Message with Button in it, so I thought the code itself should be fine

Comment: @HawkPriest I am sorry forgot to mark you on the comment

Comment: I think I understand what you are explaining. It may be the problem of the `RelativeLayout`, I can't pinpoint what for sure. It may be because you are setting the `RelativeLayout` as a shared element instead of the image. Are you wrapping all images with `RelativeLayout` to make them  circular? You can try setting the transition names to the images itself.

Comment: @LieForBananas Already tried that with no success, the rounded Images are .pngs so it's just the Relative Layout containing the Image. And well the other two RelativeLayouts work as they should, they override the Start message and have the animation in it. Just that one, first Layout has a problem with it :/ (Sorry If I understood you wrong, not my native language as you might have noticed haha)

Answer (score 0):

Well I tried to change some things and I made everything worse. Then I "repaired" it and now it works, unfortunetly I can't show you a solution for that. I try to work through the codes again

**EDIT:** @LieForBanana had the solution but I understood him wrong, indeed my first Fragment also had the Transition Name it (3x TransitionName ProfilePic). I am ashamed, it was just one silly mistake

Comment: I'm glad that we managed to resolve your problem :) Good luck!